# How to start a workflow when a document library item added or updated using sharepoint web service

Tags: sharepoint

I have an asp.net web app that can create and/or update document library items in sharepoint.  But the workflow associated with this document library does not trigger when items are created or updated.  Can I use sharepoint web service to start the workflow, passing it a item id or row id so it knows which row to start working on it?

Or do I have to use event receiver?

Comment: Provide more details: show your code, specify, how your app communicates with SharePoint, let us know how you associated the workflow with that library.

Comment: I basically use calm to add new item, update item in sharepoint document library on my asp.net web app.  The code is too big for the comment box.  In any event, it works.  The item can be added or updated.  The workflow designed by another person which normally gets triggered when a document is uploaded.  I want to trigger the workflow when my web app creates or updates document library item.

Comment: Please check whether the workflow gets triggered when you add/update list item manually directly in the document library.

Comment: The workflow does trigger when a document is uploaded.  I want to add new code into my web app to trigger the workflow after document library item is added or updated.  Something like:                        

      myWorkflowProxy.StartWorkflow(needs to add required parameters);

Comment: If start the workflow by calling workflow web service does not work, I probably need to write sharepoint event receiver to trigger workflow when document library item is added or update.  What do you think?

Comment: I saw a nintex workflow web service document that has a web service method called "StartWorkFlowOnListItem" with the following parameters: itemID: 1, listName: testdoc library,  workflowName: testworkflow01  .But I could not find anything equivalent in sharepoint workflow web service.